# How to change top padding of KivyMD TextField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am working on a questionnaire form and have a problem with the spacing between the Label and Text Field input line. You can see on the screenshot that the default distance between "Label" and "Some input text" is too big and I don't know how to change it.

Example screenshot:

[image]

I added red borders between widgets and it looks like that "spacing" I want to get rid of is actually a top padding of the MDTextField widget, right above the text input line. I tried changing it manually by accessing the `padding` attribute of the MDTextField widget but it had no effect. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to reduce that padding. Thank you!

Here is an example Python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_height: True
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 1
        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 0
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Line:
                    width: 0.5
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            MDLabel:
                font_size: '20sp'
                text: 'Label'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: self.texture_size
                halign: 'left'
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                    Line:
                        width: 0.5
                        rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            MDTextField:
                id: text_field
                mode: "line"
                size_hint_y: None
                text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
                line_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
                line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
                
        Widget:
""")


class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.main_box = MainScreen()
        print(self.main_box.ids.text_field.padding)
        self.main_box.ids.text_field.padding = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        print(self.main_box.ids.text_field.padding)
        return self.main_box



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```